# Dovecot logs showing user disconnected

Tags: mac-osx, dovecot, imap

So one of my users has an issue with connecting to the IMAP server.
She's on OSX and has tried setting up Mac Mail and Thunderbird.
In both cases the client times out when trying to connect to the server.

I thought initially it was an authentication issue, but the logs don't mention this at all, and I see from other posts the log does advise if there is an authentication issue.

Here's what the log says:

```
2015-01-06 16:28:07 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<XXXXX>, method=PLAIN, rip=10.0.XX.XX, lip=10.0.XX.XX, mpid=19264, TLS, session=<GdHESv4LdQAKAAEI> 
2015-01-06 16:28:07 imap(XXXXX): Debug: Effective uid=XXXXX, gid=XXXXX, home=/home/XXXXX 
2015-01-06 16:28:07 imap(XXXXX): Debug: maildir++: root=/home/XXXXX/Maildir, index=, control=, inbox=/home/XXXXX/Maildir, alt= 
2015-01-06 16:28:07 imap(XXXXX): Info: Disconnected: Logged out in=934 out=7174
```

So, it looks like the user is connected, then immediately disconnected, but I have no idea why this might be happening, and it only seems to be happening to this specific person.

Has anyone else come across this before, or have an idea what this is might be?

Cheers

Comment: Does her client give her any sort of error? Have they tried to log in through webmail?

Comment: Yeah. She can log into webmail it seems, so I guess it must be something on her specific Macbook rather than an issue with Dovecot. No-one else is having this problem. Back to the drawing board... :)

Comment: Possibly some firewall software on her mac?